# How to delete a Drupal sandbox project?

Tags: community-official-site

This thread: http://drupal.org/node/1077884 indicates we can delete our own sandbox projects, but I'm a little confused as to how this is done.

I see nothing on the UI on drupal.org that would allow this. If this is done directly with git, I would appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to `http://drupal.org/node/<yoursandboxnid>/edit` and at the bottom of the edit page is a delete button.